# Returning false from an else clause

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
elements.filter(function(_, e){
  terms.forEach(function(term) {
    returnValue = true;
    if(...) {
    } else {
      returnValue = false;
    }
  })
    return returnValue;
})
```

and I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to `return false` directly from the `else` clause instead of using a temporary variable since it is kind of annoying to be forced to use `returnValue`.

Thanks

Comment: you can use return false rather than using a flag/temp variable

Comment: but he wants to return the true value as well in case it is true

Comment: that forEach would result being the value after the LAST iteration, every time (unless other logic not shown overrides that) ... try array's `every` method - as for the comments above ... returning in a `forEach` is NOT the answer since returning in a forEach does not stop the forEach or cause the containing function to return

Comment: once you hit the else, do you still want to continue the forEach loop

Comment: Sure, just say `return false;`. However, that will accomplish nothing, since the return value from the `forEach` callback is ignored.

Comment: @jaromanda-x  No, once I hit the else I want to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) - that page has polyfill for elderly browsers

```
elements.filter(function(_, e) {
    return terms.every(function(term) {
        if (...) {
            ...
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
})
```

Note that you `return term.every....`

`Array#every` calls the callback until the callback returns false, in which case the value returned by `Array#every` will be false, if all iterations return true, the value returned by `Array#every` will be true ... so **every** return must be true for it to return true, otherwise it returns false and stops iterating

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Please correct me if I'm wrong but in your case, I return true when the first term is true, however, I want to return true when all term are true.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I missed it ;)

Comment: no, the `return true` keeps the loop going - as you've posted vague code, I can't be more helpful than the code above ... what is the condition? what do you do if the condition is true? unknown in the question, so I did my best in the anxswer

Comment: Your code works for me. FYI, the if condition is `item.data(term[0]) == term[1]`.

Comment: so each term is in itself an array - that's fine, it could be anything at all

Answer (score 0):

Why not just 
`return false;`
  from the forEach thing ?
Unless u ***have*** to go through all the items at least once before returning. This should let you skip using the extra variable.

And you can actually get rid of the useless if block by negating the expression

```
if(!your-expression)
   {
    return false;
  }
   return true;
```

Comment: the if/else is inside a `.forEach` - return value of `.forEach` is ignored